# Sattelite position from TLE

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication-satellite

How to get satellite position from TLE without any libraries? Because in [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing) there is no libraries like SGP4.

Comment: `Processing` is itself a `Java` library (kind of). Have you searched for Java libraries which can do what you want ? For example, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_perturbations_models#External_links). If this route works for you, please answer this question your self and _mark_ is as answered to help others.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Simply put, you cannot get any meaningful information out of a TLE without an SGP implementation.

Comment: SGP4 implementations are available as open source in many languages, as a last resort could you *rewrite* one in Processing? I think it's probably a bad idea. Another option is to adopt one of the Processing-like [python-based environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing#Related_projects) and then use a Python version of SGP4 or even [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/). Another possibility is to run SGP4 on a small separate computer (e.g a Raspberry Pi) and pass the output as binary data to your Processing platform.

Comment: If you're using Java, you really ought to look at https://www.orekit.org/